# float attribute on wrapper turns nested div offsetWidth to 0

Tags: html, css

I have a div with a float attribute, and a second level nested div in it ("#myElement").

The problem is, the float attribute somehow turns the nested div's offsetWidth to 0. When I remove the float attribute, the offsetWidth is a big valid number.

Can anyone shed some light on this for me please? Why does this happen? how can I avoid it from happening?

Thanks!

(note: The WRAPPER div has float. not the nested one. There for his question is not a duplicate)

```
<div id="wrapper" style="float: left">
    <div class="myPlayer">
         <div id=myElement>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Will try to make one now.

Comment: will need some more code.

Comment: `style="float"` is invalid.

Comment: use `style="float:left"` or `style="float:right"`

Comment: I that's what i meant. typo.
And when I try a simple html on jsfiddle it does not have that problem...
My code it too complicated to post here. Creating the nested element on the fly from server response.